# How to tell a Ruby program to close itself

Tags: ruby, console-application, exit

Is there a ruby command to tell the ruby script to close itself? What I am trying to do is this: say I'm running `ruby.rb`

```
print "What would you like to do next?"
next=gets.chomp   
next.downcase!
if next=="close"
    #this is where i want to be able to tell the program to close itself.
end
```

Is there a way to do this, and if there is, what is it?

Comment: Can you just call `exit`?

Comment: how's that work? please post an answer and explain. I'm kinda new to ruby.

Comment: puts "Press RETURN when you're done."
gets

Comment: The usual way to do this is *not* to call `exit`. Rather, it is to structure your code so that you terminate normally. For example: `def my_method; loop do; next = gets.chomp; return nil if next == "close"; <do something>; end`. The calling method receives `nil` and takes appropriate action, etc.

Comment: In future, considering waiting longer before selecting an answer. A quick selection discourages other, possibly better, answers, and is discourteous to those still preparing answers. Many SO members wait at least a couple of hours, sometimes much longer, before selecting an answer. There's no rush.

Comment: The main advantage of calling exit from the kernel is exit handlers and exit codes. Not exactly needed here, but handy for future reference.

(whoops, press enter posts the comment! Sorry about that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use

```ruby
exit
```

More information:

http://www.sitepoint.com/exit-exit-abort-raise-get-me-outta-here/

Comment: exit also accepts an integer argument.  exit 1 for example, will exit with an exit code of 1 (anything other than 0 is considered unclean or unsuccessful or in error).  abort also works and accepts a string as an argument that will be printed to STDERR upon exit.